# Insert people picker column to Sharepoint list using Rest api

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I need to insert item to sharepoint list which has multiple columns like ticket id, EmpID and ShareTicketWith which is peoplepicker field. I am able to insert record when i do not pass people picker column. But when i pass people picker column it throws error `"PrimitiveValue' node with non-null value was found when trying to read the value of a navigation property; however, a 'StartArray' node, a 'StartObject' node, or a 'PrimitiveValue' node with null value was expected."}}}"`.

I tried multiple ways to pass it but every time it throw error. Below is the code:

```
var sharedticketlist= {
"__metadata": { 'type': 'SP.Data.TestTicketListListItem'},
"Title": "1241",
"EmpID":"123456",
"TicketSharedWith":"test@test.com",
}

   $.ajax({  
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('TestTicketList')/items",  
    type: "POST",  
    headers: {  
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),  
        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"  
    },  
    data: JSON.stringify(sharedticketlist),  

    success: function(data) {  
        console.log(data.d.results);  
    },  
    error: function(error) {  
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));  
    }  
    });
```

I also tried passing author id, still it didnt work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Rest OData xml like below, it should set EmpIDId and TicketSharedWithId for this two field with user Id, for example, my current user Id is 10, then set like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sharedticketlist= {
"__metadata": { 'type': 'SP.Data.TestTicketListListItem'},
"Title": "1241",
"EmpIDId":10,//this is user id, replace with yours
"TicketSharedWithId":10 //this is user id, replace with yours
}

   $.ajax({  
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('TestTicketList')/items",  
    type: "POST",  
    headers: {  
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),  
        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"  
    },  
    data: JSON.stringify(sharedticketlist),  

    success: function(data) {  
        console.log(data.d.results);  
    },  
    error: function(error) {  
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));  
    }  
    }); 

</script>
```

Rest OData:

[OData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUiNF.png)

Result:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqxLg.png)